# Merging dictionaries with duplicate keys producing child dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am attempting to merge two dictionaries that contain n number of nested dictionaries. The behaviour of the merge needs to take a duplicate key and create a dictionary as it's value. As an example, merging these two dictionaries:

```
Data_X: {
    Data_B: {
        Data_C: "C",
    }
}

Data_Z: {
    Data_B: {
        Data_F: "F",
    }
}
```

I'd like this merge to result in:

```
Data_A: {
    Data_B: {
        Data_C: "C",
        Data_F: "F",
    }
}
```

Can't seem to find any solution that doesn't just either take the "Value" for "F" or "C" instead of adding the next dictionary to the "Value" property of "Data_B"

This is where I got to so far with taking the first "Value" instead of creating a new one but it's not quite right:

```
Dictionary<string, object>[] dictionaries = new Dictionary<string, object>[]
{
    (Dictionary<string, object>)dictX, 
    (Dictionary<string, object>)dictZ
};

var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                         .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                         .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.First());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a bit of old fashioned recursion. This assumes the structure of the dictionaries are compatible and does no error checking for attempts to merge dictionaries and string values.

```
    Dictionary<string, object> MergeDictionary(IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> dicts)
    {
        var l = dicts.SelectMany(d => d).ToLookup(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
        return l.ToDictionary(
            g => g.Key,
            g => g.Count() == 1
                ? g.First()
                : MergeDictionary(g.Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()));
    }
```

To test it you can run this, which returns your desired results.

```
    static void TestMergeDictionary()
    {
        var dbx = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Data_C", "C" } };
        var dx = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Data_B", dbx } };

        var dbz = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Data_F", "F" } };
        var dz = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Data_B", dbz } };

        var da = MergeDictionary(new[] { dx, dz });
    }
```

Comment: You are awesome! That works a treat thank you. I'm a little confused by the recursion within the linq function. I'm really poor with linq. If you have a minute to give an explanation of that linq function, I'd be so appreciative.

Comment: We use SelectMany to combine all of the dictionary keys together and turn into a lookup to group the (multiple) values together. That returns a sequence of IGrouping objects.

Comment: (I hit return while commenting and took too long...)
SelectMany returns a sequence of Key-Value pairs from all of the dictionaries. We then use ToLookup to group them by the Keys. We are then just turning the Lookup back into a Dictionary using ToDictionary(), each key is the key from the grouping. For the value, if the grouping only contains a single object then that is it (either a dictionary or a string). If the grouping contains multiple objects then these are Dictionaries that need to be merged together, which is done by calling MergeDictionary recursively.

Answer (score 1):

instead of getting the `.First()`, why not just return `.ToList()`? That will give you the key and all its associated values across all dictionaries.

```
var x = new Dictionary<string, object>();
x.Add("B", "F");
x.Add("A", "D");
var y = new Dictionary<string, object>();
y.Add("B", "G");
Dictionary<string, object>[] dictionaries = new Dictionary<string, object>[]
{
        x,
        y
};

var result = dictionaries.SelectMany(dict => dict)
                     .ToLookup(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)
                     .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList()); /* here */
```

returns(from C# interactive shell so formatting is a bit weird):

```
 Dictionary<string, List<object>>(2) { 
        { "B", List<object>(2) { "F", "G" } }, 
        { "A", List<object>(1) { "D" } } 
    }
```

Comment: As I mentioned on Maaren's answer above, this solution converts the "Value" to a List type object which then means you can't use this again to merge two dictionaries you have already merged. It will blow up trying to cast the existing value to a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Similar, and as an extension method.

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> Merge<TKey, TValue>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> me,
        IDictionary<TKey, TValue> other
    )
    {
        var keys = me.Concat(other)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
            .ToDictionary(
                x => x.Key,
                x => x.Select(z => z.Value).ToList()
            );
        return keys;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "B", "C" }, { "A", "X" } };
var dic2 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "B", "F" }, { "D", "D" } };
var dicm = dic1.Merge(dic2);
```

### Update:

With these extension methods you can keep merging.

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> Merge<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> me, IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> other)
{
    var keys = me.Concat(other)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
        .ToDictionary(
            x => x.Key,
            x => x.SelectMany(z => z.Value).ToList()
        );
    return keys;
}

public static IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> Merge<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, List<TValue>> me, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> other)
{
    return me
        .Merge(
            other
                .ToDictionary(
                    x => x.Key,
                    x => new List<TValue> { x.Value }
                )
        );
}
```

Usage:

```
var dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "B", "C" }, { "A", "X" } };
var dic2 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "B", "F" }, { "D", "D" } };
var dic3 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "B", "F" }, { "E", "D" } };
var dic4 = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "X", "F" }, { "E", "D" } };
var dicm = dic1.Merge(dic2).Merge(dic3).Merge(dic4);
```

Comment: This solution converts the "Value" to a List type object which then means you can't use this again to merge two dictionaries you have already merged. It will blow up trying to cast the existing value to a dictionary.

Comment: Well, the result obviously has to hold multiple values, so you need some list or array or hashset to hold those multiple values.

Comment: It doesn't have to hold multiple values. It has to create a new child dictionary underneath the duplicate key. I.e. "Data_B"s Value should end up containing a dictionary that has two keys inside, "Data_C" and "Data_F".

Comment: This solutions gives the compilation error: the type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage. I'm casting the dictionaries, do you know where else I have to specify the type?

Comment: I don't think this solution is what I am hoping for. I need it to create a new dictionary with both of their values in the "value" property when it tries to merge two duplicate keys.

Comment: My code compiles fine, I just checked. Make sure you have refreshed the page, I updated the code once, right after I added the 2nd code sample.

Comment: You don't need to cast the dictionaries, and you can't have 2 values in a single values property. That's why there is a list. You can change it to some other collection type, but you *something* to hold the multiple values.

Comment: The multiple values will never be at the bottom level, they will always occur above this so it's just their children (that will have non-duplicate values) to be put into a dictionary. I can't get the code to compile with a dictionary instead of list though.

Comment: I've also copied your code out exactly and the "merge" function on the "dic1.Merge(dic2)" gives the error: " the type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage"

Comment: Have you **added** the two extra extension methods, and leave the original? It could be explained by having removed the initial extension method.

Comment: Ah yep that's my bad sorry. Doesn't solve the case though unfortunately due to the fact it's creating the list object in value.